# Crawling and working on HTML for aggregation site

Tags: php, html, dom, web-crawler, aggregate

I am working on a crawling script in PHP. I am using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.

After getting the HTML I need to extract only some of the info from each page and aggregate these into my own HTML page on my site.

I am unable to understand how to proceed on this.

Any help is appreciated.

**Added**

I want to extract some posts (if related to a particular geography and topic)

Comment: Jesus. where do you start.  You will need some strategy for what you want to do.  For example, you could use a file of keywords with some of the stuff you want to extract, you could implement a list indicating what stuff you want to pull out....Lots of ways to skin this cat....

Comment: what exactly you want to extract....is it email addresses?

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions may be the way to get complex info out of the data but for simple tags you can use something like:

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$nodeList = $xpath->query("your-xpath-query");
foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
    // grab the content, attributes or whatever you'r looking for
}
```

Using Xpath queries you don't have to traverse the DOM tree manually and your script is more robust against structural changes in the sites you crawl.

I hope that gets you on the right track. For a more detailed example you have to provide more information.

Comment: since you mention XQuery: care to share a mature XQuery extension or library for PHP?

Comment: I mean xpath queries. Edited my answer.